# How to make Cyrillic characters display correctly when converting to PDF with itextpdf?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, cp1251

Does any body knows how to make itextpdf work with Cyrillic symbols?

```
I have code: 

 Font normal = FontFactory.getFont(String.valueOf(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA), "CP1251", false, 13);
 Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 36, 65);
 Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("ЗАПИСЬ!!!", normal);
 doc.add(paragraph);
```

I saw that CP1251 works good BUT for a single char -while for texts - ("ЗАПИСЬ" in my example). And it displays all the chars overlapped onto each other.

What is wrong with my code?
Thnx!

Comment: Use a font with support for those characters, such as arial.ttf, with an Unicode encoding.

Comment: An extra note on top of @PauloSoares comment: you might want to embed your chosen ttf front as well if you use something other than arial to ensure it works everywhere.  `BaseFont bf_russian = BaseFont.createFont("location/of/your/font.ttf", "CP1251", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font normal = new Font(bf_russian, 12);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download font source from network (http://fonts4web.ru/Helvetica.html#test).

Save font in your resource directory.

Act as it is in example bellow:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    /** Path to the resulting PDF file. */
    public static final String RESULT = "results/hello.pdf";
    public static final String FONT = "fonts/HelveticaRegular.ttf";

    /**
     * Creates a PDF file: hello.pdf
     * @param    args    no arguments needed
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws DocumentException, IOException {
        new HelloWorld().createPdf(RESULT);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a PDF document.
     * @param filename the path to the new PDF document
     * @throws    DocumentException
     * @throws    IOException
     */
    public void createPdf(String filename)
            throws DocumentException, IOException {
        Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);

        Document document = new Document();

        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));

        document.open();

        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World! Ты можешь использовать кирилицу.", font));

        document.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Works! Thank u.